# Identifying a field in row with 200 fields (mysql database)

Tags: php, mysql, row, field, element

I want to store 100 URL's and 100 anchor texts and they are connected as they form a link together, eg url_01 / anchor_01, and then another set is url_02 / anchor_02.

So I created 100 url fields and 100 anchor fields to store my data in a row with other customer value.

After one set has been used I want to erase it from the database and now I was thinking about adding a counter to identify which combo we have to take:

```
$count=$all_anchors['count'];
$anchor=$all_anchors['anchor_<?php echo $count; ?>'];
echo $anchor;
```

I know this works in standard PHP/HTML like:

```
<?php $count=$all_anchors['count']; ?>
<a href="http://www.website.com/?id=<?php echo $count; ?>">anchor</a>
```

But it does not work to identify the fields in the database.

Hope someone can help me out, it's important I know the ID eg the number that corresponds with the value as I want to empty it after using it.

Comment: What do you mean by:  **"it does not work to identify the fields in the database"** ?

Comment: A schema like that goes against the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of proper
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), so that's why you're having so much trouble using it.

Comment: I mean this ['anchor_<?php echo $count; ?>'] doesn't work, it's wrong syntax here. I don't know what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'm doing it completely different already, still bad design but  at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad design that doesn't scale up, to answer your ques, you have to loop through each column to match the URL value you're looking for(and ofcourse you know the row id you're looking into). 
Like

```
UPDATE TABLE SET col1=if(col1='url_01','',col1),col2=if(col2='url_01','',col2) ... where id=<row_id>
```

so on..
Similarly for anchor tags.

Recommendation:
You should be creating three denormalized tables:
 1. *urls*: to record all available urls

```
id   url        created_at
1    url_001    2017-06-10 
2    url_002    2017-06-10
```

2. *anchors*: to record all available anchors

```
id   anchor  created_at 
1    anc_001    2017-06-10  
2    anc_002    2017-06-10
```

3. *url_anchors*: mapping table, where you can attach any url with any anchor tags(without being repeat the same url or anchor values again) with customer_id as well. Recommendation is not do physical delete rather mark the row(is_deleted) as deleted if not required further.(index url_id and anchor_id)

```
id   url_id    anchor_id  customer_id created_at  is_deleted  deleted_at 
1    1         1          tom         2017-06-10  0           NULL
1    1         2          tom         2017-06-10  0           NULL
1    2         2          tom         2017-06-10  1           2017-06-10
```

Search Query:

```
update
urls u
join url_anchors ua on u.id=ua.url_id
join anchors a on a.id=ua.anchor_id
set
is_deleted=1,
deleted_at=now()
where 
u.url=<searched url>
and a.url=<searched anchor>
```

OR the delete query(not recommended):

```
delete
ua
from
urls u
join url_anchors ua on u.id=ua.url_id
join anchors a on a.id=ua.anchor_id
where 
u.url=<searched url>
and a.url=<searched anchor>
```

Comment: While this might work, it's only fossilizing the really difficult schema choice.

Comment: I would have dozens if not hundreds of clients that I need to store this for. That means I'd also have dozens of sets of 100 urls / anchors. Every client has it's own unique set of 200 values.

Comment: It doesn't really matter with millions or billions of records, the design should scale. Infact that is what you're building system for. Later with partitioning and archiving/purging it is a performant solution.

Comment: It doesn't need to loop through each column cause I know the position of the column and let it loop from there, eg the first 8 fields are client data and such, so I let it start at column 9, then once column 9 has been used it adds +1 to the counter and next time it picks the value from column 10, and colum 110 cause that's where the URL is located. But I will read the rest of all you wrote and hope I can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `clients` `table` where you will have some columns specific for the client. Example:

**clients(id, name, username, password)**

You will need a `links` `table` with a `foreign key` for the `clients` `table`, like

```
links(id, inner_text, url, client_id)
```

I know you will have more `clients` and a link is specific to a client, but you can achieve this separation with `links.client_id`. You will be able to `count` the `links` of a client like this:

```
select count(*)
from links
where client_id = 5
```

where 5 is the current `client_id` to filter the `links` with.

Comment: I understand what you mean now, that would be an awful lot of rows in that links table, wouldn't that slow down things if it has like 3000 entries? I could add a removal line of course and use a query to only select the first row from that client ID and while processing the first row removing it immidiately after the details have been used.

Comment: @DennisHamming when we talk about databases, in general "too much" starts at millions of rows. Of course, if you have very very large rows, then it will start earlier. 3000 rows should not be a problem at all.